# React router with nginx is throwing 404 page not found

Tags: nginx, webpack, react-router

When we try direct urls like `localhost/page1` nginx throwing me 404 page not found.

we are using react-router, webpack and nginx.

in nginx config we tried

```
 location /{
    try_files $uri index.html;
}
```

```
 location /{
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

```
 location /{
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
}
```

here is my webpack configuration

```
 devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    host : '0.0.0.0'
  },
```

but nothing has worked, 
Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```